# Terminal can display \uF002 while iTerm2 can't

Tags: unicode, fonts, iterm2

I set the font *MesloGS NF* for both iTerm2 and Terminal in Mac, but I found that iterm2 is not able to display `\uF0002` while Terminal can.

iTerm2 (v3.4.19):

[image]

Terminal:

[image]

The result is quite weird. Why can we get different output from the same font?

Comment: `"\uF002"` is a [private-use character](https://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html). Rendering private-use characters depends on implementation (something like *[Font Linking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-technology#font-linking)* in Windows)…

Comment: @JosefZ But it should be font-specific.